# How do I refer to the distance I’ve scrolled in a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I’m writing code for drawing in a JPanel as if it’s a canvas, where I can create shapes by clicking inside the panel. When I click, it places the dots where I want them to go, however if I scroll and then click, it places the dots where the mouse would be if I hadn’t scrolled. I assume this is because the mouse coordinates don’t change, so I’m guessing I need to add the number of pixels I’ve scrolled (horizontally and vertically). Is there a command I can use to refer to these values?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Try to include only the relevant tags for your question. In this case the issue doesn't sound like it's specific to `eclipse` or to `windowbuilder`.

Comment: Since this is the 2nd question I've edited, I'll point out re tags: Don't tag the IDE. Do tag relevant APIs like Swing.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked with Swing, but I believe you want to call:

```
JScrollPane sp = ...
Point viewPosition = sp.getViewport().getViewPosition();
```

The `viewPosition.x` and `.y` will return the offset in pixels from the top left corner.